# Parse error when trying toprogrammatically install APK from android app

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

To be as succinct as possible:

-APK file is not corrupt.

-I can browse to the APK in the phone's file system and manually install it from there without issue.

-I am using the following code to kick off the install process. File location is confirmed correct:

```
 public void installfromlocal()
    {
        String downloadfilelocation = getsharedresourcestring("updatepackagelocation");
        Log.e("installing from",downloadfilelocation);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(downloadfilelocation)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

So far what I could gather from a couple hours on the internet is that apparently I can't make my app install an APK programmatically from external storage. I can also apparently not copy the file to internal storage and install from there.

So what now? Additionally, I get no messages from Logcat. I only get a popup alerting me that there was an error parsing the apk.

Comment: Where **exactly** is `downloadfilelocation` pointing?

Comment: `downloadfilelocation` Is the path alright that you get in the log ?

Comment: Yes, the location is fine. it points to file:///storage/sdcard0/Download/org.mycompany.myapp.apk

Comment: same here. the problem shows up with android 6 and 7. with lower version no problem (same apk)

Comment: It does it for me on 4.4 and whatever Cyanogenmod 12 is.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for me (not so clear why have this issue, but i solve it).

It seems to me that when downloading with DownloadManager you cant access to the downloaded file via URI, and you get access denied (and various file not found exception error) that's why PackageInstaller cannot read at all the manifest (and that's the parse error).

This is what i did, i hope that resolve you problem as well, i know it's not elegant to say the least.

Because of DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME is deprecated i tried with COLUMN_LOCAL_URI to access the file and access its content (q is Cursor)

```
String strUri = q.getString(q.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
Uri apkUri = Uri.parse(strUri);
```

with this uri i can access and copy the file to a temp file in getExternalCacheDir()

```
ParcelFileDescriptor pfd =   context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(apkUri, "r");

InputStream inFile = new FileInputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
OutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

        //copy
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;

        while ((length = inFile.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outFile.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        outFile.flush();
        inFile.close();
        outFile.close();
```

Grab the file created and get its uri (that is accessible) and start the activity with that uri.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You should use canonical path of the file. From the docs-

> A canonical pathname is both absolute and unique. The precise definition of canonical form is system-dependent. This method first converts this pathname to absolute form if necessary, as if by invoking the getAbsolutePath() method, and then maps it to its unique form in a system-dependent way. This typically involves removing redundant names such as "." and ".." from the pathname, **resolving symbolic links (on UNIX platforms)**, and converting drive letters to a standard case (on Microsoft Windows platforms).

Comment: Why would I need to do that?

Comment: The problem is with some buggy builds of android by some OEM's, the packageInstaller gives error - EACCES (Permission denied) while you can still access the file from that path. So you need to get file, getCanonicalPath(). The package installer installs it.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Also note that your package must have read/write permission to that location.